# IntellJ App shows 'Localhost can not found' while tomcat started

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle, localhost

Currently I have a problem with IntellJ. I use gradle to generate a war file. It runs successfully under Tomcat/webApp folder(It shows UI).

While I import build.gradle file in IntellJ, Tomcat can start without any problems. But the app gives me 'the localhost can not found'(No UI page). I tried lots of solutions online. But it doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post logs/exceptions/screenshots, it's not clear when exactly and where you get this error. Does it come from IntelliJ IDEA, Tomcat or your own application?

Comment: @CrazyCoder "the localhost can not found" is from IntelliJ IDEA. I found out the reason for this is that war file excludes jsp files. If I includes jsp files, It can start up the app. However, The same war excluding jsp files can be started in Tomcat/webApp folder. Why this works?